# Json data is not parsing in swift3

Tags: ios, json, swift

this is my JSON

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQUeh.png)

I can try to parse the Json But it's not parsing 
this is the code

```
if let Media_list = jsonData["staffData"] as? NSDictionary
{
    print("this can call")

    for i in 0 ..< Media_list.count {
        if let kid = Media_list[i] as? NSDictionary
        {
            print("this the calling ")

            let dataurl = kid["url"] as? String
            self.urldummy.append(dataurl!)

            print("dataurl",dataurl as Any)                            

            let staffid = kid["staffId"]as? String
            self.staffidDummy.append(staffid!)                   
            let update = kid["updatedDate"]as? String    
            self.UpdateDummy.append(update!)                       
        }
    }                            
}
```

I want parse Json  data and append to the array, pls help me....!

Comment: `for i in 0 ..< Media_list.count` while `Media_list` is a Dictionary? Also, avoid Foundation Stuff (NSStuff) on Swift 3.

Comment: @Aleksey  if I can set  Media_list[i] as? NSDictionary  to Media_list[i] as? Any its going inside

Comment: it's showing this error:  Type 'Any' has no subscript members

Answer (score -2, accepted):

do Directly as

```
let Media_list = jsonData["staffData"] as? NSDictionary
let dataurl = Media_list["url"] as? String
```

Comment: Don't use `NSDictionary`.  Swift has the pure `Dictionary` type for a reason.

Comment: @Vikas Rajput do not use NSDictionary in swift. Swift is totally type safe language